# Post values of single row from while loop using onclick

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to pass the column values from a single row generated from a while loop. When the link is clicked I want certain values from that row to be passed as hidden fields to another page.

The code:

```
<form id="repeat" name="repeat" action="edit_user.php" method="post">
<?php
$counter = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
$color = ($counter & 1)? "#D7ECEC" : "#DEDEDE";
$counter++;
?>
<tr align="left" valign="middle" style="background: <?php print $color; ?>">
<td><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('repeat').submit();" >
    <?php echo $row['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $row['surname']; ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo $row['userlogin']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['accesslvl']; ?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['chgpasswrd']; ?></td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="lvl" value="<?php echo $row['accesslvl']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
</table>
</form>
```

What is happening is that the hidden fields are passing values for the last row of the while loop. Is it possible to do this so the hidden values being passed are from the same row of the link that is being clicked?

I've tried a few things and nothing works and I've not been able to find anything that directly relates to this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Any specific reason for using JS here? It will fail if the client has turned off the JS

Comment: No, I would rather not use JS if it is not needed. Specifically, I don't want to send the values in the URL. Cheers

Comment: You could build the hidden values into the url on the link itself

Comment: may help name="id[]" and name="lvl[]".

Answer (score 0):

You need to split this into two pages really. The first page displays the user info and link for each unique user, and the second page provides the edit form for posting the form data as follows...

```
<table>
<?php
$counter = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $color = ($counter & 1)? "#D7ECEC" : "#DEDEDE";
    $counter++;
?>
<tr align="left" valign="middle" style="background: <?php print $color; ?>">
    <td>
        <a href="edit_user.php?userID=<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>&accesslvl=<?php echo $row['accesslvl']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $row['surname']; ?>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['userlogin']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['accesslvl']; ?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $row['chgpasswrd']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

on the edit_user page you can populate the hidden fields with the information passed in by the url query string. Remember to clean the values to prevent sql injection or xss attacks. I've used htmlentities here as an example and you may want to enhance this, read the php documentation page on htmlentites for more information (ENT_QUOTES).

```
$userID    = htmlentities($_GET['userID']);
$accesslvl = htmlentities($_GET['accesslvl']);

<form action="modify_user.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (int)$userID; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lvl" value="<?php echo $accesslvl; ?>" />

    //rest of form html
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've made the change and it is still sending the values for the last row in the loop. Any other suggestions? Cheers

Comment: Probably add them within one of the <td></td> tags also you have no opening table tag

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried that but still get the same results.Cheers

Comment: Yes but you're only submitting the one form so once the while loop is running each time it replaces the values for id and lvl so once the loop has finished you will end up with the last two values only. A better approach would be to add the values to the link itself so the link becomes edit_user.php?id=<?php echo $row['userID];?>&lvl=<?php echo $row['lvl']; ?> the values are appended to the url as $_GET values